# Turn off autofit in word tables using C#

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml

How do I turn off autofit in word tables using C#? I use class

```
DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Table.
```

I mean this option:

[image]

I want uncheck this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cs
TableProperties tp = new TableProperties(
  new TableLayout { Type = TableLayoutValues.Fixed }
);
Table t = new Table(tp);
```

Make sure to add the tablelayout property to the tableproperties **after** adding stuff like tablestyles, etc.